# Best practice AsyncTaskLoader with button to load more in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an `AsyncTaskLoader` to load JSON from an API using the network. I parse the JSON and return a List with objects.

I sequentially go through this list with a click of a button. When there are no longer any List objects left, I call restart loader and pass in an offset value and call the API again. That's when the issues occurs.

While the new list is being loaded, the button trys calling the empty list because the Loader has not finished.

Is there a best practice for such a case where I want to load more objects when the user is clicking a button without causing an `nullpointerexception`?

I was thinking of disabling the button while the loader is working and then enabling it when it finishes. What would be the best approach for that?

Comment: Show code what you have tried?

Comment: Instead of using  button for loading more data you can use endless scroll listener for listview

Comment: thanks for the suggestion because it made me think of something else. I would only like to display one item at a time. I believe a viewpager with a custom view that has a text box could work. What would be the best way to implement the pageradapter calling for more items?